# Hazelcast: right way to deploy on cluster

Tags: java, configuration, distributed-computing, hazelcast

*What is the right way to deploy Hazelcast on one REST-server and 5 worker machines cluster? Should I start Hazelcast 5 server instances  (one on each worker) and 1 `HazelcastClient` on REST server?*

### I have

- One REST server machine, which handle all user requests;
- Five worker machines in a cluster, each of machines keeps some data in local file system. That data is definitely to big to keep them in RAM, I need Hazelcast only to distribute my search query through cluster.

### I want

On user request, search through data of each of 5 worker machines and return result to user. User request will be accepted by REST-server machine, than REST-server will send search `MultiTask` to each worker in a cluster. Something like:

```
public MySearchResult handleUserSearchRequest(String query) {
    MultiTask<String> task = new MultiTask<String>(query, Hazelcast.getCluster().getMembers());
    ExecutorService executorService = Hazelcast.getExecutorService();
    executorService.execute(task);
    Collection<String> results = task.get();
    return results.stream().reduce(/*some logic*/);
}
```

### P.S.

*How to launch all 6 Hazelcast instances from single place (Spring Boot application)?*

Comment: What operations are you doing at Worker machines and are those standalone JVMs or some web servers ?

Comment: @A.K.Desai I'm doing heavy IO operations (lookups through hude on-disk indices) and yes - that are standalone JVMs

Comment: Great, then you can make use of Hazelcast nodes itself as workers. On what condition do you want to distribute the load? If you have already partitioned data then you can simply call submitToKeyOwner which submits the task to the node containing the data. Based on this, I can suggest a quick design approach.

Comment: @A.K.Desai One point - I have already partitioned data, but with help of Apache Spark. So Hazelcast have no idea how data are distributed. Hazelcast shouldn't ue cluster-wide data structures. Actually data lays at local file system of each worker, and `submitToKeyOwner` is not a case. I can not use Spark instead of Hazelcast for this task - it has problems with launching two sessions from single JVM at once

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply have a script that can run your main class containing the node startup code, those many number of times.

Understanding your usecase, I have given a sample code for creating a cluster and submitting a task to all the nodes from a Driver class in your case REST client.

Run the below class 5 times to create a cluster of 5 nodes under TCP/IP configuration.

```
public class WorkerNode {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        /*
        Create a new Hazelcast node.
        Get the configurations from Hazelcast.xml in classpath or default one from jar
         */
        HazelcastInstance workerNode = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();

        System.out.println("*********** Started a WorkerNode ***********");
    }

}
```

Here is the NodeTask containing your business logic to do the IO operations.

```
public class NodeTask implements Callable<Object>, HazelcastInstanceAware, Serializable {

    private transient HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance;

    public void setHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {
        this.hazelcastInstance = hazelcastInstance;
    }

    public Object call() throws Exception {

        Object returnableObject = "testData";

        //Do all the IO operations here and set the returnable object

        System.out.println("Running the NodeTask on a Hazelcast Node: " + hazelcastInstance.getName());

        return returnableObject;
    }
}
```

Here is the driver class from your REST client:

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient();

        IExecutorService executor = client.getExecutorService("executor");
        Map<Member, Future<Object>> result = executor.submitToAllMembers(new NodeTask());

        for (Future<Object> future : result.values()) {
            /*
            Aggregation logic goes here.
             */
            System.out.println("Returned data from node: " + future.get());
        }

        client.shutdown();

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Sample Hazelcast.xml configuration:

```
<hazelcast xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config/hazelcast-config-3.8.xsd"
           xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <network>
        <port auto-increment="true" port-count="100">5701</port>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="false">
                <multicast-group>224.2.2.3</multicast-group>
                <multicast-port>54327</multicast-port>
            </multicast>
            <tcp-ip enabled="true">
                <!--Replace this with the IP addresses of the servers -->
                <interface>127.0.0.1</interface>
            </tcp-ip>
            <aws enabled="false"/>
        </join>
        <interfaces enabled="false">
            <interface>127.0.0.1</interface>
        </interfaces>
    </network>
</hazelcast>
```

[image: Architecture]

Comment: thank you for so full answer! As I understand, I should pack `WorkerNode` to separate jar, and run that jar on each node in a cluster, right? Also does your configurations imply embedded or client plus member approach https://hazelcast.org/deployment-operations-guide/#network-architecture-and-configuration?

Comment: Also one note from here http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/faq.html: `In the client-server topology, you create a cluster of nodes and scale the cluster independently. Your applications are hosted on the clients, and the clients communicate with the nodes in the cluster to reach data.` I do not need to keep data at Hazelcast at all, I need Hazelcast just to grab data to REST-server from cluster. Maybe client-server mode is better for my needs?

Comment: Yes, go Client-Server mode irrespective of whether you want to keep data or not. In that way, it will be horizontally scale-able. If you are not planning to keep data in memory then start JVM with less -Xmx based on how memory intensive your IO operations are.

Comment: and Yes, just have all the classes and dependent jars in a single jar and run the jar independently so they can form the cluster. As long as they use the same hazelcast.xml, they will automatically form cluster.

Comment: thank you a lot!! Please, two more questions. 99,9% of time Hazelcast will idle. 1) *How to make my instances take as less as possible RAM in idle mode? Could I have 6 `HazelcastClient`s?*  2) *I should start each Hazelcast node  with CLI, right?*

Comment: Sure. 1)Hazelcast nodes are nothing but standalone JVMs. So once allocated you can not change. But you can come up with your own custom logic to do Auto Scaling which can bring up/down more instances whenever you need. If it's AWS, EC2 Instance autoscaling will take care of it. 2) No need to have multiple `HazelcastClient` instances instead make it singleton and use that in your REST server. If you have more than one REST servers, you can have one client per server. 3) Yes, you can bring them up using CLI.